# In R, Create Summary Data Frame from Multiple Objects

Tags: r, dataframe, apply

I'm trying to create a "summary" data frame that holds some high-level stats about a few objects in my R project. I'm having trouble even accomplishing this simple task and I've tried using For loops and Apply functions with no luck.

After searching (a lot) on SO I'm seeing that For loops might not be the best performing option, so I'm open to any solution that gets the job done.

I have three objects: `text1` `text2` and `text3` of class "Large Character (vectors)" (imagine I might be exploring these objects and will create a NLP predictive model from them). Each are > 250 MB in size (upwards of 1 million "rows" each) once loaded into R.

My goal: Store the results of `object.size()` `length()` and `max(nchar())` in a table for my 3 objects.

**Method 1: Use an Apply() Function**

Issue: I haven't successfully applied multiple functions to a single object. I understand how to do simple applies like `lapply(x, mean)` but I'm falling short here.

**Method 2: Bind Rows Using a For loop**

I'm liking this solution because I almost know how to implement it. A lot of SO users say this is a bad approach, but I'm lacking other ideas.

```
sources <- c("text1", "text2", "text3")
text.summary <- data.frame()

for (i in sources){ 
    text.summary[i ,] <- rbind(i, object.size(get(i)), length(get(i)),
   max(nchar(get(i))))
}
```

Issue: This returns the error `data length exceeds size of matrix` - I know I could define the structure of my data frame (on line 2), but I've seen too much feedback on other questions that advise against doing this.

Thanks for helping me understand the proper way to accomplish this. I know I'm going to have trouble doing NLP if I can't even figure out this simple problem, but R is my first foray into programming. Oof!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try for example:

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(list(text1,text2,text3), 
       function(x) c(objectSize=c(object.size(x)),length=length(x),max=max(nchar(x)))))
```

You'll obtain a `matrix`. You can coerce to `data.frame` later if you need.

Comment: This worked really nicely, thanks. I will learn more about `do.call()` !